# How to execute external programs in Amazon EC2?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

I want to execute external programs in Amazon EC2 instance. I have tried using `exec` and `shell_exec` but these two functions didn't work due to missing permissions and security.

I need that because I'm trying to create **Apache vhosts** using shell script to add sub-domains dynamically by PHP web tool. I tried adding apache user in `etc/sudoers` but it didn't work.

Is there another way to execute external programs in Amazon EC2 in PHP?

Comment: well, shell_exec is exactly what you need, you have to correctly setup AWS server permissions so PHP can run programs

Comment: @LuninRoman is it a security threat by allowing shell_exec to execute commands in production server?

Comment: No, it is fine if you setup all the permissions correctly, read more about Linux permission and user groups. But it is the only possible solution - if you have no permission you can't do anything, no matter which function you are using in php or something

Comment: any other means to achieve this functionality?